# Evento OnItemCommand do Repeater não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou com problema em um Repeater no webform, onde o evento OnItemCommand não está funcionando. Ele deveria ser acionado quando clico no linkbutton.

Codigo aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterImagens" runat="server" 
        OnItemCommand="repeaterImagens_ItemCommand" 
        OnItemDataBound="repeaterImagens_ItemDataBound">
       <ItemTemplate>

...

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbExcluir" runat="server"
                        CommandName="excluir"
                        CommandArgument="<%# ((String)Container.DataItem) %>" 
                        OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Confirma a exclusão desta imagem?'));">
                </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code behind C#

```
protected void repeaterImagens_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName.Equals("excluir"))
    {
           ExcluirArquivo(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
     }
}
```

Testei no modo debug, ao clicar no Linkbutto nada acontece, nem ao mesmo chama o evento ItemCommand.

Comment: Olá @user5482, talvez o erro na esteja no OnClientClick, creio que você deve colocar um returna explicitamente, algo deste tipo:

OnClientClick="return window.confirm('Confirma a exclusão desta imagem?');">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione `return false` depois do if no `OnClientClick`.

Ou seja:

```
OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Confirma a exclusão desta imagem?')) return false;">
```

Edit:

Depois de várias sugestões, o OP descobriu que o erro era causado devido à pagina ter o atributo `EnableViewState="false"`.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração, porem o problema persiste. É como se nada acontecesse, o evento ItemCommand não é chamado.

Comment: já pôs o `breakpoint` dentro do seu `ItemCommand` para ver se pelo menos está entrando?

Comment: @Tafarel, já coloquei sim, é como se o evento nem fosse chamado.

Comment: @TafarelChicotti o unico evento que é requisitado ao clicar no lnikbutton é o page load da página.

Comment: Consegui resolver, era outra coisa bem nada haver, que só foi dar problema nessa parte da página. A página estava setada com EnableViewState="false".

Comment: @ÉricoSouza ponha a solução numa resposta sua e quando puder marque como respondido para o caso de alguém ter o mesmo problema.

Comment: @ÉricoSouza Não era bem isso quer queria dizer, era marcar a **sua** resposta como resolvida. Vou editar a perguntar e por as conclusões dos comentários, mas julgo não merecer a rep neste caso, foi um esforço conjunto.

Comment: @Omni, só uma ajuda aqui. COmo que eu marco minha resposta como resolvida?

Comment: @ÉricoSouza crie uma resposta nova (no fundo da página tem um botão "Adicionar outra resposta" e coloque lá as suas conclusões. Salvo erro terá de esperar 48h para poder aceitar a sua resposta como solução, mas acho que será o mais correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Altere da seguinte maneira seu `LinkButton` que é para funcionar

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbExcluir" runat="server"
    CommandName="excluir"
    CommandArgument="<%# ((String)Container.DataItem) %>" 
    OnClientClick="javascript: return confirm('Confirma a exclusão desta imagem?');">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Caso não funcione, remove o `javascript:`

Comment: Tafarel, testei de ambas maneiras, e o erro persiste. Acredito que pode não ser o javascript, ou evento OnclientClick. Pois mesmo sem o evento, o problema continua.

Comment: Ao clicar no linkbutton ele nem chama nenhum evento. =[

Comment: @ÉricoSouza a pagina é gerada correctamente? Não está nenhuma tag mal fechada? se puser o linkbutton fora do repeater funciona?

Comment: @Omni a pagina é gerada corretamente sim. Mas vou fazer uma verificação novamente no código gerado. E o linkbutton funciona normalmente fora do repeater.

Comment: @ÉricoSouza uma dica, se vc remover o `((String)Container.DataItem)` e deixar só `Container.DataItem` é pra funcionar normalmente

Comment: o problema persiste, ao clica no linkbutton, é chamado o evento page_load da pagina.

Comment: mas dpois do page_load ele não vai pro ItemCommand? pq ele vai pasar antes pelo load msm

Comment: Não vai não, apenas verifica se é postback. No caso, está sendo true.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver, era outra coisa bem nada haver, que só foi dar problema nessa parte da página. A página estava setada com EnableViewState="false".

Agradeço a ajuda.